# Admin Taxonomy Terms - Orderby Term Field

Tags: admin, wp-admin, taxonomy, sort

I have a custom value which is being stored as `term_group` but in the admin panel I would like to order them by that term group. I'm able to sorta do this through this function, but there's a problem:

```
function change_term_order( $args, $taxonomies ) {
    if ( is_admin() && 'tax_products' !== $taxonomies[0] )
        return $args;

    $args['orderby'] = 'term_group';
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'change_term_order', 10, 2 );
```

This only works if the user sorts on one of the columns, not on initial page load. I tried to modify the filter to be `get_terms` but it just errored out half way down the page. Does anybody know the correct filter to change ordering categories and taxonomy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the answer after some trial and error / tons of searching, this looks like the correct filter, just need to make sure we're in the admin section and we're in the correct taxonomy.

```
/**
 * Modify the admin listed order of terms
 *
 * @param String $orderby
 * @param Array $args
 * @param Array $taxonomies
 *
 * @return String $orderby
 */
function change_term_order( $orderby, $args, $taxonomies ) {

    if ( is_admin() && 'tax_products' !== $taxonomies[0] ) {
        return $orderby;
    }

    $orderby        = 'term_group';
    $args['order']  = 'ASC';

    return $orderby;
}
add_filter( 'get_terms_orderby', 'change_term_order', 10, 3 );
```